# Unable to make jqplot bargraphs clickable, when using in popup

Tags: onclick, popup, jqplot

I am using jqplot for my modal-popup and I wish to make each bar clickable.
I initially had an issue of rendering the plot in popup for which i used

```
 $('#id').bind('shown',function() {
         plot.replot();
    });
```

Which renders the plot fine.
But the jqplot click event "jqplotDataClick" doesnt seem to work.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Click event works fine with bar graph I had an issue with bind, I do not have to replot currently, graph rendering fine without replot( Emptying the popup data on close)